# table-stripped not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 design at the moment and I have a few pages where the table-stripped class isn't in effect but it is called with "table table-stripped"..
Here is the link to one of those pages
http://savamarkovic.com/dal/index.php/about/ranks?lang=dal

I've read that it's like that when the HTML syntax is not right..but I don't see where it's like that for the table..
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled "striped" incorrectly.

Change `class="table table-stripped"` to `class="table table-striped"`.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't have seen that for the life of me. I appreciate your help!